# Is every positive integer the rank of an elliptic curve over some number field?

Tags: nt.number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves

For every positive integer $n$, is there some number field $K$ and elliptic curve $E/K$ such that $E(K)$ has rank $n$?

It's easy to show that the set of such $n$ is unbounded. But can one show that *every* positive integer is the rank of some elliptic curve over a number field?

The analogous question for a fixed number field is expected to have a negative answer (c.f. e.g., [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/137970/is-it-expected-that-every-natural-number-is-the-rank-of-some-elliptic-curve-over)) but is still conjectural. But I wonder if one might be able to prove a positive answer to the question I asked above.

Comment: I am not sure whether it is fair to say that the fixed number field case should admit a negative answer; of course that comes down to a famous unsolved problem. For the existence of $E/K$, an iterated application of Silverman's specialization theorem reduces us to proving that the group of sections of the elliptic scheme $A_{1,n+1} \to A_{1,n}$ has rank $n$, generated by the $n$ 'point doubling' sections $(x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto (x_1,x_1;x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, etc. (Here $A_{g,n}$ is the space of $n$-pointed abelian varieties of dimension $g$). This should be true.

Comment: -1. I think this question is a little silly. What could possibly be the use of knowing the answer? I mean, if you could reduce the Goldbach conjecture for $2n$ to the existence of an elliptic curve of rank $n$ over some number field,  then I would see the point. As the matter stands I'm afraid I don't.

Comment: @RP_ I would -1 your comment if I could. Since when does usefulness of the result dictate whether the question is good for this site? Which ranks are possible over a *fixed* number field is similarly useless, and yet it's a very interesting open problem.

Comment: @RP: What would be the use of knowing the answer of any question on this website? Unless you're only in it for cryptographic applications, this question is useful because of human curiosity.

Comment: One may ask more generally: given a representation of a finite group $\rho : G \to \mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{Q})$, does $\rho$ arise as the Galois module $E(L) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$ for some elliptic curve $E/K$ and some extension $L/K$ with Galois group $G$. We can also fix the number field $K$. If I recall correctly, if one replaces "arises" by "appears inside" then for function fields $K=\mathbb{F}_p(t)$ these kinds of things are known.

Comment: @Wojowu: I am merely pointing out the existence of the phenomenon 'idle curiosity'. If you would label Goldbach's conjecture as such, that is up to you. Anyway, I wanted to give my reasons for my downvote, not enter into a discussion about the value of mathematics, so I will leave it here.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that my comment sounds less than clear, so let me add that apart from the remark in the first sentence, I do regard there both $K$ and $E$ as varying. Basically I am saying that a version of Silverman's specialization theorem can be used $r$ times over an $r$-dimensional char. $0$ base $T$ assuming that there exists an elliptic scheme $A/T$ such that $A(T) / \mathrm{tors} \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. From this point of view the problem is geometric, and I am guessing that an explicit such $A/T$ is given by $A_{1,n+1}  / A_{1,n}$ (but any other construction would suffice).

Comment: This other question I asked may be of relevance: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/88175/regarding-the-surjectivity-of-the-class-numbers

Comment: @StanleyYaoXiao: Your question should be infinitely harder than this one. I don't think there is much of a similarity between a class number and a Mordell-Weil rank.

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov The Mordell-Weil group of $E$ is isomorphic to the relative Picard group of $E/\mathbb{Q}$, so this is a natural analogue. By the way it is  known that every abelian group is the Picard group of some Dedekind domain (Claborn 1966). One may ask the same thing while restricting the class of abelian groups and/or Dedekind domains considered.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: I didn't think of this, thanks for noting it! It makes sense, then. I assumed the class group was similar to a Selmer group, which includes only an upper bound on the rank. Still it looked to me that Stanley's question should be harder than the current one, but I could be off.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: That rel Picard over $\mathbb{Q}$, though, kills the much more mysterious Shafarevich-Tate part; the Selmer group I think should be the true analogy. It is very easy to construct many $E/K$ of rank zero, much harder to construct number fields of class number one (apart from finitely many known cases).

Comment: @VesselinDimitrov Yes it's also natural to consider the Tate-Shafaverich group, from the point of view of the BSD conjecture and analytic class number formula. Both are special cases of the Tamagawa number conjecture, which uses Galois cohomology. The class number arises as the boundary in the Poitou-Tate localization sequence. The ideal class group and the Mordell-Weil group are both Picard groups but for Dedekind domains which are of somewhat different nature.

Comment: It should be possible to prove the analogous statement over function fields. For a quadratic twist of a fixed elliptic curve $E$, Katz proved that $1/2$ the twists have analytic rank $0$ and half the twists have analytic rank $1$, in the large $q$ limit. It should be possible to check by explicitly examining monodromy that the root numbers of different quadratic twists are suitably independent.

Comment: So for $q$ sufficiently large we can show the existence of an elliptic curve $E$ and discriminants $D_1,\dots, D_k$ such that of the $2^k$ twists generated by $D_1,\dots, D_k$, $n$ have analytic rank $1$and the rest have rank $0$. Then one just has to use the analytic rank $1$ part of the BSD conjecture (which I think is now known in full generality over function fields?) and deduce that $n$ of these twists have algebraic rank $1$, hence the pullback to the composite of quadratic extensions has rank $n$.

Comment: The "trick" here is we can use $q \to\infty$ results because the question lets us pass to any finite extension. A similar result would follow over number fields from heuristics for the distribution of $L$-functions. In particular, it requires our heuristics to be true only in the 100% setting, and not in the power savings setting rqeuired by the boundedness of rank arguments over the integers.